# How to receive async func message from webview and pass on to app with Kotlin Android?

Tags: javascript, android, kotlin, android-webview

I am new developing android apps. I am trying to create a WebView that executes a Javascript and the idea is that send data to an interface in the app. I have some implementations but I don't know when I use a async func I am not receiving the data to the interface. For example in the sample.html if I write just the notation async before func not work but if I remove it, it works.

I have read on internet about it, tells that I can use it or that I have to do some type of handler.

**MainActivity**

```
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient
import android.webkit.WebView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val mFilePath = "file:///android_asset/sample.html"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        runWebView()
    }


    private fun runWebView(){
            val webView = findViewById<View>(R.id.webView) as WebView
            webView.webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient() {}
            val settings = webView.settings
            settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
            settings.domStorageEnabled = true
            webView.addJavascriptInterface(JavaScriptInterface(this), "Android")
            webView.loadUrl(mFilePath)

    }

    /**
     * Receive message from webview and pass on to native.
     */
    class JavaScriptInterface(val context: Context){
        @JavascriptInterface
        fun showMessageInNative(message:String){
            println("lest go ")
        }
    }

}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.shield_android_client">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.ShieldAndroidClient">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**sample.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<body>
<p style="font-size:20pt;">This is web view</p>
<input id="inputField" style="height:50px;width:300px;font-size:20pt;" type="text" value="">
<br><br>
<input onClick="sendMessage()" style="height:50px;width:300px;font-size:20pt;" type="button"
       value="Send data to native"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    async function sendMessage() {
        var valueReceived =  document.getElementById("inputField").value;
        Android.showMessageInNative(valueReceived);
    }
</script>
<style>
    body {
    background-color: #93B874
    }
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

**activity.main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="311dp"
        android:layout_height="548dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.497" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]